# Подсветка синтаксиса Java не поддерживает Java 9, 10 и 11

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, редактор, подсветка-синтаксиса

Ключевое слово `var` не подсвечивается, например тут: [Как найти минимальное значение в массиве в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887073/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b2-java/887086#887086)

Так же не подсвечивается ключевое слово `module`, например тут: [где скачать jre 11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/886352/%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-jre-11/886762#886762)

Это известные баги SO и их скоро исправят?

Comment: На SO внешняя подсветка синтаксиса https://github.com/google/code-prettify. Если хотите, чтобы они добавили подсветку var - или запостите баг на странице проекта, или почините сами, и откройте pull request. Скорее всего будет достаточно добавить var в [JAVA_KEYWORDS](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/453bd5f51e61245339b738b1bbdd42d7848722ba/js-modules/prettify.js#L137), может быть еще тест на него написать.